# blank data appearing in the database without user registration

Tags: php

I have a user registration form which accepts data and saves it in the Database, but sometimes in the database there is an empty record saved. Why is this problem there?

My code is below. 
Html textboxes and following code is in the index.php file

```
if(isset($_POST[btnSubmit]))
{
    if( !empty($txtName) && !empty($txtEmail) && !is_numeric($txtEmail) ) 
    {
               //data saving code goes here......
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you missing your quotes around btnSubmit? `$_POST['btnSubmit']`

Comment: Please give us more information. When does it saves empty records ? When you submit empty fields of when $_POST['btnSubmit'] is not expected to be set ? Where are your variables initialized ?

Answer (score 3):

**php 5.5**

```
if( !empty(trim($txtName)) && !empty(trim($txtEmail)) && !is_numeric($txtEmail) ) 
        {
                   //data saving code goes here......
        }
```

**< php.5.4**

```
$txtName = trim($txtName);
$txtEmail = trim($txtEmail);

if( !empty($txtName) && !empty($txtEmail) && !is_numeric($txtEmail) ) 
        {
                   //data saving code goes here......
        }
```

Comment: First `empty`, *then* `trim`!

Comment: Incredible; three upvoters and one answerer has not bothered to actually check this code: http://3v4l.org/JOGRj